# unwind segue animation error

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I have two view controllers the first is called "Login View controller" followed by a navigation controller and then another view controller called "Registration View Controller". I found an article online detailing the proper way in performing an unwind segue animation and placed this code inside of "Login View Controller"

```
 override func segueForUnwinding(to toViewController: UIViewController,
                                from fromViewController: UIViewController,
                                identifier: String?) -> UIStoryboardSegue {
    return UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: identifier, source: fromViewController, destination: toViewController) {
        let fromView = fromViewController.view
        let toView = toViewController.view
        if let containerView = fromView?.superview {
            let initialFrame = fromView?.frame
            var offscreenRect = initialFrame
            offscreenRect?.origin.x -= (initialFrame?.width)!
            toView?.frame = offscreenRect!
            containerView.addSubview(toView!)
            // Being explicit with the types NSTimeInterval and CGFloat are important
            // otherwise the swift compiler will complain
            let duration: TimeInterval = 1.0
            let delay: TimeInterval = 0.0
            let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut
            let damping: CGFloat = 0.5
            let velocity: CGFloat = 4.0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, usingSpringWithDamping: damping,
                           initialSpringVelocity: velocity, options: options, animations: {
                            toView?.frame = initialFrame!
            }, completion: { finished in
                toView?.removeFromSuperview()
                if let navController = toViewController.navigationController {
                    navController.popToViewController(toViewController, animated: false)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

What happens now when I press the back button inside of the "Registration View Controller" is the code successfully executes but then removes the "Login View Controller" from view and stays on the "Registration View Controller". After switching out "toView?.removeFromSuperview()" to "fromView?.removeFromSuperview()", it successfully stays on the "Login View Controller" but now if I press the button to take me to "Register View Controller" it just sends me back to "Login View Controller" essentially creating an infinite loop.

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove a view from its superview before popping the VC. I'd get rid of that line entirely. 

If that doesn't do it, it depends on how you're pushign to the registration VC. You might not be instantiating a new one each time properly.  In conjunction with removing this view, you're probably pushing a VC that no longer has its main view, since you removed it from superview, which shows the VC underneath?

Comment: @JakeT. I just removed the line you suggested and I keep getting stuck on the "Login View controller"